# how to add a button on an jpg image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, png, jpeg

I have a jpg and a PNG image file, on which I want to add a button, the image is huge, so when we zoom in the image, the image expands, the button should also expand and contract, I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work. any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to have your button on top of your image.
You may also need an [`AnimatedContainer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) to change the width and height of your button.

If you already tried this solution, can you share with us your code ?